# R Programming - Combine lists with similar names after looping

Tags: r, loops

I currently have the following loop.

```
    > margin_values
$margINCBJP
[1] 0.8481856 0.9165585 0.9270849 0.7932756 0.8296131 0.8284826 0.7584834 0.2566567

$margINCTRS
[1]          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA  0.84499199  0.73135251 -0.06664292

$margBJPTRS
[1]          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA  0.01650935 -0.02713086 -0.32329962


for(i in 1:length(margin_values)) { 
  nam <- paste("x", i, sep = "")
  assign(nam, margin_values[[i:i]])
}
```

This creates separate lists starting at `x1` to `xn`. How can I then automatically combine the numbers from all the lists to create one list? I know I can manually type     `c(x1, x2, x3...)`     all the way up until n, but since n is variable, is there anyway to have R simply do    `c()`    on all values starting with x? For this example, n=3, but depending on parameters I have earlier in my code it may change.

Comment: It would be better to assign the numbers to list elements to begin with. You can initialise an empty list with the right length and add to a new index each loop

Comment: `do.call(c, margin_values[1:n])` or just `unlist(margin_values[1:n])` - is that all you're looking for?

Comment: `unlist(margin_values[1:length(margin_values)] `  did the trick. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Just ran into this myself and here is what I came up with (tweaked for you of course):

`total<-c(lapply(ls(pattern = "x"),get))`

This will create a list, total, with each element being one of your variables starting with x